# DB Schema: Database connection issue

Tags: db-schema

I am trying to connect to caboodle database using windows authentication for importing table structures to DB Schema. In connection wizard, it gives me option to select database from the list after I add my username and password. However, after selecting any database, it errors out with following error:

The server principal "user" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context.

Please note, I did not select Model database from the list, still its failing for model database.

Please assist with the solution to this.

I am trying to connect to caboodle database using windows authentication for importing table structures to DB Schema. In connection wizard, it gives me option to select database from the list after I add my username and password.

I expect it to connect with CDW database from the dropdown list.